# Solve $(y')^2 - xy' + y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am so confused,  how to get a solution of following differential equation:

$$(y')^2 -xy' + y = 0$$

**My Thought:**

Try solving $y'$ to get $y' = \dfrac{ x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 4y}}{2}$ and now its unsolvable. Kindly help, appreciated.

Comment: I have added My thought to the question. (actually it was already there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take the derivative of your equation, you get:

$$2y'y''-xy''-y'+y' = 0$$

or

$$y''(2y'-x)=0.$$

Let $v=y'$ and we have $v'(2v-x) = 0,$ so either $v'=0$ and $v=c$ or $v=x/2$.

Then $y'=c$ and so $y=cx+d$ or $y'=x/2$ and $y=x^2/4.$

Plugging the first into the original equation gives $d=-c^2$.  So there are two solutions $y=cx-c^2$ for some constant $c$ and $y=x^2/4$.  I don't know if this is all the solutions.

Comment: Just realised it's clairaut form, solution is in same way.

Answer (score 2):

we can rewrite the O.D.E as
$$(y'-\frac{x}{2})^2=-(y-\frac{x^2}{4})$$
now let

$$u=(y-\frac{x^2}{4})$$
$$u'=(y'-\frac{x}{2})$$
so
$$(u')^2=-u$$
$$2u'u''=-u'$$
$$2u''=-1$$
$$u=-\frac{1}{4}x^2+C_1x+C_2$$
so the solution will be
$$-\frac{1}{4}x^2+C_1x+C_2=(y-\frac{x^2}{4})$$
$$y=C_1x+C_2\tag 1$$
Plugging the equ (1) into the original equation gives
$$C_2=-C_1^2$$
so the solution will be
$$y=C_1x-C_1^2$$

Comment: the solution $u'=0$ should be added too.